# Read data from files and pass to template using jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I have two files where I keep data:

**file1.txt**

```
Title1
Desc1
```

**file2.txt**

```
Title2
Desc2
```

I then have a jade template where I need to pass lines 1 and 2 from each file above. Here is the jade template:

```
.title #{title}
.desc #{desc}
```

Here is my **server.js:**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

How do I pass the lines from each of the data files to the template?

Comment: read the file then. res.render('index', {title:titleFromFile,desc:descFromFile });

Answer (score 1):

You need to read from disk, parse the format, and then pass the parsed data to your template.

Reading from disk is rather simple: use `fs.readFile()`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  // do something with "data" here...
});
```

Maybe you need to read both files for a single request? In that case you will have to nest your callbacks. Alternatively, you could use a promise library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) to simplify the callbacks.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(filename1, 'utf8', function(err, data1) {
  fs.readFile(filename2, 'utf8', function(err, data2) {
    // ... now parse in here
  });
});
```

Once you have the data, you'll want to parse it. Given your examples, your format is very simple. Here's how you might parse it:

```
var lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
var title = lines.shift();
var desc = lines.shift(); 
// or, maybe "lines.join('\n')" to support multiple lines
```

Finally, you want to render you template to the client. If you're using Express (based on the code example alone -- you didn't specify) you can pass your template variables as properties on the second parameter to `res.render()`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    // reading the file failed, report error to the user
    if (err) return next(err);

    // parse the data
    var lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    var title = lines.shift();
    var desc = lines.shift();

    // render template
    res.render('index', {title: title, desc: desc});
  });
});
```